# BSOD when using an HDMI cable

Tags: windows-7, hdmi, bsod, intel-graphics, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a Dell XPS 15 (L502x) running Windows 7 x64 Home Premium, and have a BSOD issue when connecting an external screen.

I tried connecting two screens - one with HDMI > DVI and HDMI > HDMI, and the second with the same HDMI > HDMI cable.

With both screen I get a BSOD after a while of usage(random BSOD, could occur even when not interacting with the computer).

Here's a small analysis of two relevant dumps, one which states that the problem is with the nvidia graphics card, and the second says the problem is with the internal card.

Any ideas on why this would happen?

First:

```
UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP (7f)
This means a trap occurred in kernel mode, and it's a trap of a kind
that the kernel isn't allowed to have/catch (bound trap) or that
is always instant death (double fault).  The first number in the
bugcheck params is the number of the trap (8 = double fault, etc)
Consult an Intel x86 family manual to learn more about what these
traps are. Here is a *portion* of those codes:
If kv shows a taskGate
        use .tss on the part before the colon, then kv.
Else if kv shows a trapframe
        use .trap on that value
Else
        .trap on the appropriate frame will show where the trap was taken
        (on x86, this will be the ebp that goes with the procedure KiTrap)
Endif
kb will then show the corrected stack.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000008, EXCEPTION_DOUBLE_FAULT
Arg2: 0000000080050033
Arg3: 00000000000406f8
Arg4: fffff8800f22fa3f

Debugging Details:
------------------

TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\modclass.ini, error 2

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x7f_8

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  9

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8000308a769 to fffff8000308b1c0

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff800`00ba4d28 fffff800`0308a769 : 00000000`0000007f 00000000`00000008 00000000`80050033 00000000`000406f8 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff800`00ba4d30 fffff800`03088c32 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
fffff800`00ba4e70 fffff880`0f22fa3f : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiDoubleFaultAbort+0xb2
fffff880`0d12df70 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nvlddmkm+0x1a3a3f


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nvlddmkm+1a3a3f
fffff880`0f22fa3f ??              ???

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  3

SYMBOL_NAME:  nvlddmkm+1a3a3f

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nvlddmkm

IMAGE_NAME:  nvlddmkm.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  503f8bb8

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x7f_8_nvlddmkm+1a3a3f

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x7f_8_nvlddmkm+1a3a3f

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Second:

```
UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP (7f)
This means a trap occurred in kernel mode, and it's a trap of a kind
that the kernel isn't allowed to have/catch (bound trap) or that
is always instant death (double fault).  The first number in the
bugcheck params is the number of the trap (8 = double fault, etc)
Consult an Intel x86 family manual to learn more about what these
traps are. Here is a *portion* of those codes:
If kv shows a taskGate
        use .tss on the part before the colon, then kv.
Else if kv shows a trapframe
        use .trap on that value
Else
        .trap on the appropriate frame will show where the trap was taken
        (on x86, this will be the ebp that goes with the procedure KiTrap)
Endif
kb will then show the corrected stack.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000008, EXCEPTION_DOUBLE_FAULT
Arg2: 0000000080050033
Arg3: 00000000000406f8
Arg4: fffff8800591c802

Debugging Details:
------------------

TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\modclass.ini, error 2

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x7f_8

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  b

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff800030cd769 to fffff800030ce1c0

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff800`00ba4d28 fffff800`030cd769 : 00000000`0000007f 00000000`00000008 00000000`80050033 00000000`000406f8 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff800`00ba4d30 fffff800`030cbc32 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
fffff800`00ba4e70 fffff880`0591c802 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiDoubleFaultAbort+0xb2
fffff880`0c780fe0 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : igdkmd64+0x2e8802


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
igdkmd64+2e8802
fffff880`0591c802 ??              ???

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  3

SYMBOL_NAME:  igdkmd64+2e8802

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: igdkmd64

IMAGE_NAME:  igdkmd64.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4d41a3e1

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x7f_8_igdkmd64+2e8802

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x7f_8_igdkmd64+2e8802

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Third:

```
UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP (7f)
This means a trap occurred in kernel mode, and it's a trap of a kind
that the kernel isn't allowed to have/catch (bound trap) or that
is always instant death (double fault).  The first number in the
bugcheck params is the number of the trap (8 = double fault, etc)
Consult an Intel x86 family manual to learn more about what these
traps are. Here is a *portion* of those codes:
If kv shows a taskGate
        use .tss on the part before the colon, then kv.
Else if kv shows a trapframe
        use .trap on that value
Else
        .trap on the appropriate frame will show where the trap was taken
        (on x86, this will be the ebp that goes with the procedure KiTrap)
Endif
kb will then show the corrected stack.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000008, EXCEPTION_DOUBLE_FAULT
Arg2: 0000000080050033
Arg3: 00000000000406f8
Arg4: fffff8800f23b837

Debugging Details:
------------------

TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\modclass.ini, error 2

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x7f_8

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  9

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8000329c769 to fffff8000329d1c0

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff800`0493dd28 fffff800`0329c769 : 00000000`0000007f 00000000`00000008 00000000`80050033 00000000`000406f8 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff800`0493dd30 fffff800`0329ac32 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
fffff800`0493de70 fffff880`0f23b837 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiDoubleFaultAbort+0xb2
fffff880`0e1bbff0 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nvlddmkm+0x19d837


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nvlddmkm+19d837
fffff880`0f23b837 ??              ???

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  3

SYMBOL_NAME:  nvlddmkm+19d837

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nvlddmkm

IMAGE_NAME:  nvlddmkm.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  503f8bb8

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x7f_8_nvlddmkm+19d837

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x7f_8_nvlddmkm+19d837

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: Strange, using Google, igdkmd64.sys appears to be an Intel graphics driver while nvlddmkm.sys appears to be an Nvidia driver.  This comment appears to match @KoKo's answer.  Do you know if you have two graphic adapters active at the same time?  If yes, I would try upgrading to latest drivers from both vendors.

Comment: See my comment on KoKos answer. Moreover, I've updated the drivers on both graphics card with no help. the igdkmd64.sys problem happened only when connecting the second screen(a TV), and I'm quite sure that for some reason the nvidia card didn't kick into action and let the built in card do all the work

Answer (score 0):

Are you using two monitor by connecting one to the nvidia card and the other to the mobo integrated video port? I think the two might be conflicting in terms of hardware or software, it's hard to determine. You might want to just buy a standalone video card that supports two monitors natively instead of trying to get your integrated video chip to work with your nvidia card.

Comment: Indeed I'm using two monitors, but Since it's a Dell Laptop, what it does is use the Nvidia card for both screens when connecting an external screen, rather than just use the internal card when using a single monitor. meaning, I'm using only one graphics card at a time

Comment: oh sorry I didn't notice it's a laptop. In that case, I'd say first try re-install your OS clean, if the problem still persists, it's likely a hardware issue or a driver issue that is currently not getting fixed, I'd go with another brand/model.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you say that both monitors can be displayed to using your laptop's NVIDIA graphics card.

What display adapters show up in Device Manager using Computer Management?  See my example below.

If both monitors can be driven by the NVIDIA adapter I would disable the Intel adapter if it  showing up active on your system.

[image]

Comment: I do indeed have two - Intel and NVIDIA .I'll try that and see if I get any BSODs.

Comment: Unfortunately, even when disabling the built in graphics card, I get a BSOD.

Comment: Can you post the dump analysis of your latest BSOD like the others you have posted?  I'm curious to see which driver wasa involved.

Comment: Just posted it now, see the third analysis